# La sombra de mi CardView no se ve bien

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: Previsualización de la aplicación]

Tengo un recycler view y en el diseño del "elemento único" le he puesto un CardView. En la previsualización de dicho elemento se ve la sombra del CardView correctamente, el problema viene cuando trato de ejecutar la aplicación en mi móvil, donde no hay rastro de esta sombra, os dejo el código:

Este es el XML que tiene el elemento del diseño del RecyclerView, que es un CardView para tener la sombra que quiero obtener en la vista:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSkillImage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSkillsNames"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Este es el código del XML que contiene el RecyclerView que es al que le quiero aplicar dicho CardView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlMyPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:paddingStart="25dp">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMyPhoto"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivMyPhoto"
                android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAnswerTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/answer_title"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPurple"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMyName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvAnswerTitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/my_name"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#8D8D8D"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMyJob"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvMyName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/my_job"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#535353"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSkillsTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rlMyPhoto"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Aptitudes"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvSkills"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvSkillsTitle"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rvSkills"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="Conóceme"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMyDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescriptionTitle"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:justificationMode="inter_word"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="@string/my_value"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Por aquí os pongo el Adapter del RecyclerView por si fuera necesario para resolver este problema que estoy teniendo:

```
    package com.isaac.lookatme.recyclerview

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.CenterCrop
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.RoundedCorners
import com.isaac.lookatme.R
import com.isaac.lookatme.model.Skills

class SkillsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    var skills: MutableList<Skills> = ArrayList()
    lateinit var context: Context

    fun SkillsAdapter(skills: MutableList<Skills>, context: Context) {

        this.skills = skills
        this.context = context

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = skills.get(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.skills_design, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return skills.size
    }

}

class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val url = view.findViewById(R.id.ivSkillImage) as ImageView
    val name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSkillsNames) as TextView

    fun bind(skills: Skills) {

        name.text = skills.nameSkill
        url.loadUrl(skills.urlImage)

    }

    fun ImageView.loadUrl(url: String) {
        Glide.with(context).load(url).transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(25)).into(this)
    }

}
```

Dejo también las dependencias que estoy usando por si sirve de ayuda en la respuesta, ahí van:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

A ver de que puede ser. He probado con el parametro `elevation` pero tampoco hace nada y no se de que puede ser o donde puedo mirar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Issac, sería bueno agregaras como tratabas de aplicar la elevación, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente si quieres agregar una sombra a tus `CardView`, debes usar la propiedad:

```
app:cardElevation="10dp"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        app:cardElevation="10dp">
```

programaticamente lo puedes realizar de esta forma, donde `View` es la vista a la cual puedes aplicar la elevación:

```
ViewCompat.setElevation(View, 10);
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estuve buscando y tienes razón, tenía que añadirle eso, PERO no ha sido mi solución, se sigue sin mostrar la sombra, no se si tiene algo que ver que mi RecyclerView tenga orientación horizontal, aunque no creo. También lei que tenía que habilitar la aceleración por hardware en el archivo Manifest, pero tampoco me ha resuelto el problema, ¿alguna otra idea?

Comment: Me respondo a mi mismo, si que funciona, sería que le había añadido poca elevación, pero noto que la sombra se aprecia muy poco, hay alguna otra forma se hacer que esta se vea un poco más? O que no tenga tanta opacidad? Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿cuantos dp estas definiendo como elevación o que valor estas definiendo ? @Isaac

Comment: Ahora le he añadido 12 de elevación, pero lo que te digo, la sombra se aprecia poco, no se si existe alguna manera de que tenga menos opacidad @Jorgesys

Comment: Me parece que el problema es que los CardView están muy juntos uno de otro, Mencionas que tu orientación es horizontal, podrías agregar una imagen de como se ve con 12dp de elevación?

Comment: Si claro, voy, dame un momento

Comment: Listo, he añadido la imagen en la pregunta arriba del todo. Me ha salido bastante grande asi que se ve de sobra @Jorgesys

Comment: Ahora veo, los elementos están muy juntos pero dime por favor cual es la dependencia que estas usando @Isaac

Comment: Ahora mismo he salido de casa pero luego cuando vuelva o mañana te respondo con la que estoy usando, ¿vale? Muchas gracias ☺️ @Jorgesys

Comment: Ya he añadido a la pregunta las dependencias que estoy usando, lo he añadido al final del post @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0):

a mi tambien me paso lo mismo y pense que es problema de mis dependencias, pero al final lo resolvi porque tenia `android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:largeHeap="true"`y ese era el problema nada mas los omiti y ya me funciono[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaría aplicando un poco de Padding y cambiando el color a la sombra para saber que está pasando.

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorNewGreen"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Al cambiar dar Padding, cambiar el color tanto del background como de la sombre podrás apreciar mejor que propiedad es la que realmente necesitas cambiar para el efecto que tú quieras.

Espero ayudar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usar estas dos propiedades juntas en el CardView:

```
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
translationZ="10dp"
```

Si aún así no te funciona, prueba darle márgenes al CardView, porque muchísimas veces pasa que por ejemplo el CardView tiene 200dp de alto y su sombra sobresale unos 50dp, pero el RecyclerView se adapta al alto del CardView sin tener en cuenta esos 50dp de sombra.